# How to count number of occurencies of the same line?

Tags: bash, uniq

I have file that looks like this:

```
1747834 222
1747834 222
1747834 222
1747834 222
2514112 32636
2514112 32636
2514112 32636
```

For each line I want to count number of its occurencies and write it to the third column, each line should be divided by new line like this:

```
1747834 222 4

2514112 32636 3
```

I managed to write this script:

```
while read line; do a=`grep "$line" input | wc -l`; echo -e ${line}; echo -e "${a}\n"; done < input_uniq
```

where input_uniq is output of

```
 cat input | uniq
```

but unfortunately I get output like this:

```
1747834 222
4

2514112 32636
3
```

If I use just one echo, output is very strange  (Basically, $line is overwritten by $a at the beginning) So I am looking for another way to do what I need or for suggestion how to fix my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is:

```
sort file | uniq -c 
      4 1747834 222
      3 2514112 32636
```

Although the line count is append to the start not the end so here is an `awk` script to do exactly that:

```
$ awk '{seen[$0]++}END{for (line in seen) print line, seen[line]}' file
1747834 222 4
2514112 32636 3
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it. But I eventuelly find out that my problems have arised from windows line endings, so I am a bit cleverer for the future:)